# Laravel 5 - proper way to update record with many-to-many association?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel, trying to figure out proper way of saving data with associations. I'm using version 5.3

For example: I have **Publications** that belongsToMany **Authors**

DD of request:

```
array:4 [▼
    "_token" => "something"
    "_method" => "PATCH"
    "name" => "Something"
    "authors" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "780"
        1 => "840"
    ]
]
```

First I've tried to do this:

```
public function update(Request $request, Publication $publication)
{
    $publication->update($request->all());
}
```

But got "unknown column authors" SQL error.

I've tried different approach:

```
public function update(Request $request, Publication $publication)
{
    $publication->update($request->except('authors'));
    $publication->authors()->sync($request->input('authors'));

    return redirect('/');
}
```

This time it works as expected. My question is: am I doing it right? Or there is a better / simpler way? May be possibility to do this update without explicit "slicing" or request? (`$request->except('authors')`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safer and better option would be using

```
public function update(Request $request, Publication $publication)
{
    $publication->fill($request->all())->save();
    $publication->authors()->sync($request->input('authors'));

    return redirect('/');
}
```

And also setting `$fillable` property in your Publication class

```
class Publication extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'other_field'];
}
```

Also, it would be nice if you validate your input. Further reading: [Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation)

Comment: SQL error(1054 Unknown column 'authors' in 'field list')

Comment: How did you set your `$fillable` property?

Comment: I've used guarded. `protected $guarded = array();`

Comment: Please set `protected $fillable = ['name'];` and `protected $guarded = ['*'];`. When you set `protected $gurarded = [];` all properties are considered safe, and Laravel tries to fill `authors` field, even though it does not exist in database. Also, instead of only `name`, you should set properties that are safe for mass assignment. It's almost always better to blacklist everything and whitelist only desired properties, and not the other way around

Comment: Aha! Now I understand it. Thank you. But, is it right, that I can't save related data in one line and always need to be explicit and call the sync() method?

Comment: Sometimes it's possible to save model in one line, but not in this case.

If you have one-to-one relation, and do something like
`$post = Post::with('author');`  
`$post->title = 'Other title';`  
`$post->author->name = 'Othername';`  
`$post->push();`  
You will save model and it's relation with one method call.